# Mixing ANSI 1992 JOINs and COMMAs in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

i'm trying the following MySQL query to fetch some data:

```
SELECT m.*, t.*
FROM memebers as m, telephone as t
INNER JOIN memeberFunctions as mf ON m.id = mf.memeber
INNER JOIN mitgliedTelephone as mt ON m.id = mt.memeber
WHERE mf.function = 32
```

But i always get the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'm.id' in 'on clause'
```

The column does exists and the query works fine with only one table (e.g. when i remove telephone)

Does anybody know what I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have a typo? "memebers" isn't a word, do you mean "members" instead? It would explain why MySQL is complaining about not finding `id` in `m`.

Comment: What is join condition for telephone table? right now this looks like a full join of m+t and then inner join of two tables with that

Comment: Try using proper join syntax. What's the telephone table for, considering you don't use it any of the joins?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems your requirement is to join `members` table but you are joining with `telephone` table. just change their order.

```
SELECT 
    `m`.*,
    `t`.* 
FROM
    `memebers` AS `m` 
    JOIN `telephone` AS `t` 
    JOIN `memeberFunctions` AS `mf` 
        ON `m`.`id` = `mf`.`memeber` 
        AND `mf`.`function` = 32 
    JOIN `mitgliedTelephone` AS `mt` 
        ON `m`.`id` = `mt`.`memeber`;
```

Hope this helps you. Thank you!!

Comment: This is the incorrect answer. Do not use this technique. You should not mix implicit and explict joins. @sebas has the correct answer.

Answer (score 16):

According to [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), you shouldn't mix up both notations when building up joins. The comma you are using to join  `memebers as m, telephone as t`, and the subsequent calls to `inner join`, are triggering the unknown column error.

To deal with it, use `CROSS/INNER/LEFT JOIN` instead of commas.

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same
>   precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 was interpreted as
>   ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). Now JOIN has higher precedence, so the expression
>   is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3)). This change affects statements
>   that use an ON clause, because that clause can refer only to columns
>   in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes
>   interpretation of what those operands are.

For pedagogic purpose, I'm adding the query as it, I think, should be:

```
SELECT m.*, t.*
FROM memebers as m 
    JOIN telephone as t
    JOIN memeberFunctions as mf ON m.id = mf.memeber AND mf.function = 32
    JOIN mitgliedTelephone as mt ON m.id = mt.memeber
```

Since you're not joining `t` and `m`, the final result will be a cartesian product; you might want it to be revised.

I Hope it helped.