# Mysql throwing "Unknow column column_name in on clause" error when i trying to join two tables.

Tags: mysql

I am trying to show distinct hotel rooms which are having low price(Hotel with low priced room, No need to show other rooms in that hotel) from below two tables.
But i am getting the error "Unknow column column_name in on clause". Please check my query

```
    SELECT  r.*,h.*
    FROM hotels_temp h,rooms_temp r
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT 
        hotel_code,MIN(amount) mincost
      FROM 
        rooms_temp 
      GROUP BY hotel_code
    ) m ON r.amount = m.mincost and h.hotel_code=r.hotel_code 
    ORDER BY r.amount
    LIMIT 30
```

**Table Name:** hotels_temp

[image]

Table Name: rooms_temp

[image]

Comment: Your problem is here: `FROM hotels_temp h,rooms_temp r`... there's no JOIN.

Comment: do not mix commas and ansi joins: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11180050/1291428

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve this myself by below query.

```
    SELECT * FROM hotels_temp
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  r.amount,r.hotel_code FROM rooms_temp r
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT hotel_code,amount, MIN(amount) mincost FROM rooms_temp  GROUP BY hotel_code
        ) m ON 
        r.amount = m.mincost GROUP BY r.hotel_code
    ) ht ON 
    ht.hotel_code=hotels_temp.hotel_code LIMIT 0,30
```

Answer (score 0):

As per mu assumption, you need rooms with lower cost and maximum one room per hotel. Then you acheive this as follows,

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.*,h.*
FROM rooms_temp r LEFT JOIN hotels_temp h ON h.hotel_code = r.hotel_code
ORDER BY r.amount DESC LIMIT 0,30
```

Here i assume r.id is room's unique id.