# MySql: LEFT JOIN, ORDER and LIMIT managing them all

Tags: mysql, sql

The following mysql will return the first 10 posts in my DB, along with the comments assocaited with those ten posts, and the user associated with post, the whole thing sorted by the title of the post.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 0,10 ORDER BY posts.title) as post 
       LEFT JOIN comments AS comment ON comment.postId = post.id, 
       authors AS author 
WHERE post.authorId = author.id
```

How do I sort by author.name ? changing posts.title to author.name gives me an error:

```
Table 'comment' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
```

Comment: Show the query with the problem.

Comment: Just... add `ORDER BY author.name` to the very end

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11180050/1291428

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch ORDER BY and LIMIT in the subquery. However, you also want to move the ORDER BY to the main query, not the subquery. So you want:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 0,10) as post 
LEFT JOIN comments as comment on comment.postId = post.id, authors as author 
WHERE post.authorId = author.id ORDER BY author.name, posts.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer - misread question

You are doing an order by on an inner select, which is only using the posts table, as well, it only orders THAT select, not the entire select. What you want is to order by the author.name on the outer select.