# Why SQL error "unknown column" in JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm querying 3 tables using `JOIN` and I need to use it twice for the same table. I'm getting an "Unknown column" error message. I have tried various ways using aliases but I just can't resolve the problem. Any ideas?

```
SELECT DISTINCT jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn.atendente
     , jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn.btn_name
     , pagseguro.atendente
     , pagseguro.produto 
  FROM jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn, pagseguro
 INNER JOIN produtos pp ON jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn.btn_name = pp.cod_produto
 INNER JOIN produtos ps ON pagseguro.produto = ps.cod_produto
 WHERE jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn.payer_email = '$email' 
    OR pagseguro.email = '$email' 
   AND pp.modo_consulta = 'imediata' 
    OR ps.modo_consulta = 'imediata'
```

Messsage:

> Unknown column 'jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn.btn_name' in 'on clause'

**Structure of tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE produtos 
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    produto varchar(20), 
    modo_consulta varchar(30)
    );

CREATE TABLE jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn 
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    btn_name varchar(20), 
    atendente varchar(30),
    payer_email varchar(50)
    );

CREATE TABLE pagseguro 
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    produto varchar(20), 
    atendente varchar(30),
    email varchar(50)
    );
```

**Sample Data:**

```
    INSERT INTO produtos
    (modo_consulta, produto)
    VALUES
    ('imediata', 'BR0120'),
    ('imediata', 'BR0130');

    INSERT INTO jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn
    (atendente, btn_name, payer_email)
    VALUES
    ('sibila', 'BR0120', 'me@lettura.com'),
    ('lua', 'BR0130', 'me@lettura.com');

    INSERT INTO pagseguro
    (atendente, produto, email)
    VALUES
    ('patricia', 'BR0120', 'me@lettura.com'),
    ('lua', 'BR0130', 'me@lettura.com');
```

---

**Update**. Desired output is unique row `atendente` from 2 tables `pagseguro` and `jos_easypaypalbuttons` when matching table `produtos.mod_consulta` is `'imediata'`:

```
ATENDENTE   BTN_NAME PRODUTO  MOD_CONSULTA
-----------------------------------------
sibila      BR0120            imediata   
lua         BR0130            imediata
patricia             BR0120   imediata
```

Comment: did you aim to do a cross join on pagseguro?

Comment: Does the column `btn_name` exist in the `jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn` table?

Comment: Can't be sure without running the query against tables, but you really want to remove the comma from this line: `FROM jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn, pagseguro`

Comment: See [Mixing JOINs and COMMAs in a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179991/mixing-joins-and-commas-in-a-query) (I'm sorry this is not a duplicate, wrong flagging here. However you'll find very useful informations to improve your query)

Comment: @Sebas I am pretty sure that is a correct dup, the mixing of joins can cause these issues

Comment: @ wootscootinboogie I am to join pagseguro with produtos and jos_easypaypalbottons with produtos

Comment: @Kevin Brydon I'm gonna edit with table structure jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn.btn_name does exist.

Comment: @Adry See this [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62121/1) -- I think you want to use this. The problem is you are mixing join syntax.

Comment: @ypercube output is unic records 'atendente' from the 2 tables pagseguro and jos_easypaypalbuttons when field for product (pagseguro.produto and jos_paypalbuttons.btn_name) corresponds to 'imediata' on table produtos.

Comment: @bluefeet I was already using it, thank you! :)

Comment: Please edit the question and add the rows you want as output. It's better.

Comment: @ypercube I did it, hope I did it as you meant :)

Comment: I will note the incorrect answer is selected as the one the OP used on the duplicate.

Comment: @ypercube thanks a lot for addressing me updated with what I'm trying to output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your intended output, I conclude that you want the `FULL JOIN` (and/or the `UNION`) of the two tables {jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn, pagseguro}. (and add some decoration from produtos, too)

```
SELECT DISTINCT two.atendente
     , two.btn_name
     , two.produto
     , pp.modo_consulta
  FROM (
        SELECT  COALESCE(ipb.atendente, pgs.atendente) AS atendente
        , COALESCE(ipb.btn_name,pgs.produto) AS zzz
        , COALESCE(ipb.payer_email,pgs.email) AS payer_email
        , ipb.btn_name AS btn_name
        , pgs.produto AS produto
        FROM jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn ipb
        FULL JOIN pagseguro pgs ON pgs.atendente = ipb.atendente
                                 AND pgs.produto = ipb.btn_name
        ) two
 JOIN produtos pp ON pp.produto = two.zzz
 WHERE two.payer_email = 'me@lettura.com'
   AND pp.modo_consulta = 'imediata'
        ;
```

The same can be accomplished by putting the `FULL JOIN` subquery into a CTE:

```
WITH two AS (
        SELECT  COALESCE(ipb.atendente, pgs.atendente) AS atendente
        , COALESCE(ipb.btn_name,pgs.produto) AS zzz
        , COALESCE(ipb.payer_email,pgs.email) AS payer_email
        , ipb.btn_name AS btn_name
        , pgs.produto AS produto
        FROM jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn ipb
        FULL JOIN pagseguro pgs ON pgs.atendente = ipb.atendente
                        AND pgs.produto = ipb.btn_name
        )
SELECT DISTINCT two.atendente
     , two.btn_name
     , two.produto
        , pp.modo_consulta
 FROM two
 JOIN produtos pp ON pp.produto = two.zzz
 WHERE two.payer_email = 'me@lettura.com'
   AND pp.modo_consulta = 'imediata'
        ;
```

The result:

```
 atendente | btn_name | produto | modo_consulta 
-----------+----------+---------+---------------
 lua       | BR0130   | BR0130  | imediata
 sibila    | BR0120   |         | imediata
 patricia  |          | BR0120  | imediata
(3 rows)
```

UPDATE XXX: avoiding the FULL JOIN BY using an UNION. (YMMV. sigh)

```
SELECT DISTINCT two.atendente
     , two.btn_name
     , two.produto
        , pp.modo_consulta
 FROM   (
         SELECT  COALESCE(ipb.atendente, pgs.atendente) AS atendente
        , COALESCE(ipb.btn_name,pgs.produto) AS zzz
        , COALESCE(ipb.payer_email,pgs.email) AS payer_email
        , ipb.btn_name AS btn_name
        , pgs.produto AS produto
        FROM (
                SELECT aa.atendente AS atendente
                        ,aa.produto AS zzz
                FROM pagseguro aa
                UNION
                SELECT bb.atendente AS atendente
                        ,bb.btn_name AS zzz
                FROM jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn bb
                ) uu
        LEFT JOIN pagseguro pgs ON pgs.atendente = uu.atendente
                        AND pgs.produto = uu.zzz
        LEFT JOIN jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn ipb ON ipb.atendente = uu.atendente
                        AND ipb.btn_name = uu.zzz
        ) two
 JOIN produtos pp ON pp.produto = two.zzz
 WHERE two.payer_email = 'me@lettura.com'
   AND pp.modo_consulta = 'imediata'
        ;
```

Aftermath: Do note that `{jos_easypaypalbuttons_ipn, pagseguro}` are essentially isomorphic. A lot of complexity could be avoided by combining these two tables, maybe adding an indicator/typetag field. Adagium: `the need for a UNION (often) indicates a data-modelling problem`

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL does not have a `FULL JOIN`, it also does not have a `WITH` clause.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to improvise, probably by using a LEFT JOIN + RIGHT JOIN and/or an UNION.

Comment: @wildplasser that works thanks a lot! It's further more than my knowloge can go and I will now spend time studying it.