# SQL Query: why does adding another table change the results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with MySQL. Lets say i have this query Q1:

**Q1:**

```
select cn.idConteudo, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim)
from navegacaolog nl, conteudoNo cn                  
where nl.idConteudoNo = cn.idConteudoNo AND
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120
```

the results are the following:

[image]

However if i add another table to "from", lets say: utilizador table (Q2), the results are very different as the next figure shows:

[image]

**Q2:**

```
select cn.idConteudo, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim)
from navegacaolog nl, conteudoNo cn,        utilizador                  
where nl.idConteudoNo = cn.idConteudoNo AND
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120
```

I don't understand why, the fact of adding another table (without using it in where clause) has so much importance. Can somebody please give me some help?

Kind regards

Comment: does your anoter table has the same field? maybe you can try to combine them with Join, i think this is not a clear query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not specified a join condition, so what you're getting is the FULL CROSS JOIN which produces a row for every possible combination of rows in the base tables.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

I find that using the ANSI syntax for joins avoids this confusion. Don't just use the commas in the FROM clause... use actual JOIN clauses...

```
select cn.idConteudo, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim)
from navegacaolog nl
JOIN conteudoNo cn ON nl.idConteudoNo = cn.idConteudoNo
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120
```

Comment: And if i want to add another table?: The original query its something like this:
`
select  cn.idConteudo, SUM(uta.pontuacao), 
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim))

from navegacaolog nl, conteudoNo cn, 
utilizadortesteavaliacao uta
`
where  nl.idConteudoNo = cn.idConteudoNo AND
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120 AND
  uta.idUtilizador = nl.idUtilizador`

Comment: Then you add another join clause and a condition. You can have as many JOINs as you want.

Comment: So, something like this: `select cn.idConteudo, sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim))
from navegacaolog nl
JOIN conteudoNo cn ON nl.idConteudoNo = cn.idConteudoNo
JOIN utilizadortesteavaliacao uta ON nl.idUtilizador = uta.idUtilizador

where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120

group by cn.idConteudo` right? Unfortunatly it still does not work, i think that the SUM of the timestamps should't produce a value so high

Comment: Yes that is what it's supposed to do. If you have a row in the first table which matches two rows in the second table, you will get two rows of output. If you only want to count one, you'll have to use some grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Results have not changed, just that each result has been repeated number of times equal to rows in new table.
And reason is that you have added new table without any join in where clause so you have a cross join.

Comment: Hum, ok, i got it. So you are telling me that i have to make a relation between them to get the same results. Write?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't realise you're casting a cartesian product using the non-ansi SQL join syntax.

If you had n results before, adding that new table of x records would logically provide n * x total results.

Use ANSI syntax to understand better your queries (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11180050/1291428 to see the common mistakes as well)

This

```
SELECT cn.idConteudom SUM(uta.pontuacao), SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim))
FROM navegacaolog nl
    JOIN conteudoNo cn ON nl.idConteudoNo = cn.idConteudoNo AND
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120
    JOIN utilizador uta ON uta.idUtilizador = nl.idUtilizador 
GROUP BY cn.idConteudo
```

is your query, normalised. Joining a table (`utilizador`) without a join condition means realising a `CROSS JOIN`, or better said a cartesian product.

Comment: Well, what i want is to do something like this:
`select  cn.idConteudo, SUM(uta.pontuacao), 
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim))

from navegacaolog nl, conteudoNo cn, 
utilizadortesteavaliacao uta

where  nl.idConteudoNo = cn.idConteudoNo AND
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120 AND
  uta.idUtilizador = nl.idUtilizador 


group by cn.idConteudo
`

Im trying to use joins to do that, but, so far, the close i got is Jasmine answer. I want to adapt it now to do what i wrote above. How can i do that?

Comment: I thought in something like this: `SELECT cn.idConteudo, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim))
FROM navegacaolog nl
    JOIN conteudoNo cn ON nl.idConteudoNo = cn.idConteudoNo AND
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120
    CROSS JOIN utilizadortesteavaliacao uta

where uta.idUtilizador = nl.idUtilizador

group by cn.idConteudo` But it does't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Done. What i really wanted is something like this:

```
select Q1.idConteudo, Q2.PONTUACAO, Q1.TEMPO
from 
    (select cn.idConteudoNo AS idConteudoNo, cn.idConteudo AS idConteudo,sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim)) AS TEMPO
        from navegacaolog nl
            JOIN conteudoNo cn 
                ON nl.idConteudoNo = cn.idConteudoNo

        where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120

        group by cn.idConteudoNo) AS Q1

    ,

    (select nl.idConteudoNo AS idConteudoNo, sum(uta.pontuacao) AS PONTUACAO
        from navegacaolog nl
            JOIN utilizadortesteavaliacao uta 
                ON nl.idUtilizador = uta.idUtilizador
        where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, nl.dataInicio , nl.dataFim) > 120

        group by nl.idConteudoNo
    ) AS Q2

WHERE

    Q1.idConteudoNo = Q2.idConteudoNo
```

But all you said was correct. the problem is that it was counting several times the same thing.

Thanks to all

Kind regards