# selecting from multiple tables vs JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display all fixtures(who plays 'against' who) for a current user so I wrote SQL query

```
SELECT 
  fixture.*
FROM
  sport_team_player AS team_player, sport_team AS team 
INNER JOIN sport_fixture AS fixture 
  ON (`team_player`.`team_id` = fixture.`team1_id` OR `team_player`.`team_id` = fixture.`team2_id`)
WHERE 
  team_player.`team_id` = team.`team_id` AND team_player.`player_id` = '16'
```

And this doesn't work and tells me that team_player.team_id does not exist

but if I join the second table instead of selecting from multiple tables it works just fine.

PS. This is not the best way to write such query but it's generated by ORM module..

EDIT:

Result would be list of fixture data like

```
------------------------------
|fixture_id|team1_id|team2_id|
------------------------------
|1         | 2      | 3      |
------------------------------
```

Comment: Please give us a portion of the intended result

Comment: What is the exact error message? It might be that you are mixing JOIN and comma operator which will give you a `Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause'`. See the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: @OcasoProtal yep thats the case but why does it work if I join the second table instead of comma?

Comment: Precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN. That's why when you mix comma with other join types this error occur.

Comment: didn't new this thanks!

Comment: "who plays 'against' who(m)" ?

Comment: sorry for bad English, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN. That's why when you mix comma with other join table operators [Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause'] error occur. Same query will work if you specify the cross join ( to get a Cartesian product of the first two tables) instead of commas, because then in the from clause the table operators will be evaluated from left to right:

```
SELECT 
    fixture.*
FROM
    sport_team_player AS team_player
    cross join sport_team AS team 
    INNER JOIN sport_fixture AS fixture 
    ON (team_player.team_id = fixture.team1_id OR team_player.team_id = fixture.team2_id)
WHERE 
  team_player.team_id = team.team_id AND team_player.player_id = '16'
```

Comment: You was the first one with correct answer, accepted and thanks:)

Comment: A cross join is not warranted here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. Should result to the same query as yours;

```
SELECT fixture.*
FROM  sport_team_player AS team_player
JOIN  sport_team AS team 
ON    team_player.`team_id` = team.`team_id` AND team_player.`player_id` = '16'
INNER JOIN sport_fixture AS fixture 
ON (`team_player`.`team_id` = fixture.`team1_id` 
     OR `team_player`.`team_id` = fixture.`team2_id`)
```

You shouldn't mix up both notations when building up joins. The comma you are using to join team_player and team , and the subsequent calls to inner join, will most probably trigger unknown column error.

Comment: This one works as expected, also I have told that if I use join instead of comma it works but why doesn't comma work?

Comment: refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179991/mixing-ansi-1992-joins-and-commas-in-a-query)

Comment: @insanebits `JOIN`s give you more controll over what data you fetch and are over all a more cleaner way to aggregate SQL, get used to `JOIN`s, they are easier to handle than you might think

Comment: @DanFromGermany I know but it's the buggy object relation mapping module(ORM) which automatically creates this query

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT f.*
  FROM sport_team_player p
  JOIN sport_team t
    ON t.team_id = p.team_id 
  JOIN sport_fixture f
    ON p.team_id IN(f.team1_id,f.team2_id)
 WHERE p.player_id = 16;
```