# How to LEFT JOIN 3 tables ON multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I've been stuck on this one for a little bit.  I have 3 tables and want to match tables 2 and 3 to table 1 on different columns.

```
tasks:
id      | item1_id       | item2_id   
--------------------------------------------
1       | 4              | 5   
2       | 5              | 6   
3       | 6              | 7  
--------------------------------------------

item1:
id      | item1_name     
--------------------------------------------
4       | item1_a              
5       | item1_b              
6       | item1_c              
--------------------------------------------

item2:
id      | item2_name     
--------------------------------------------
5       | item2_a              
6       | item2_b              
7       | item2_c              
--------------------------------------------
```

What I've been trying is:

```
SELECT tasks.id AS taskID, item1.name AS item1Name, item2.name AS item2Name
FROM tasks LEFT JOIN (item1 CROSS JOIN item2) 
ON (tasks.item1_id = item1.id AND tasks.item2_id = item2.id),
users, notes 
WHERE users.task_id = tasks.id
AND notes.task_id = tasks.id;
```

I'm returning tasks but not the info from item1 or item2.

Comment: check this SO link, you'll find useful informations and examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11180050/1291428

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you doing a `cross join`?  Just do two `left join`s:

```
SELECT tasks.id AS taskID, item1.name AS item1Name, item2.name AS item2Name
FROM tasks LEFT JOIN
     item1
     on tasks.item1_id = item1.id LEFT JOIN
     item2
     on tasks.item2_id = item2.id LEFT JOIN
     users
     on users.task_id = tasks.id LEFT JOIN
     notes
     on notes.task_id = tasks.id;
```

This will keep all records in `tasks`, along with all matching fields from the other tables.

Note:  you shouldn't mix `join` criteria by using both `on` clauses and `where` clauses.  In fact, the rule is simple.  Eschew `where` clauses for `join`s.  Always use `on`.

Comment: Thanks... I think I was over thinking it.  Also I didn't realize it was bad form to mix ON and WHERE.  Is it ok to use WHERE on tasks after my LEFT JOINS?

Comment: @AndrewSinagra . . . It is bad form to use the `,` in the `from` clause.  If you want a `cross join`, then be explicit.  Modern join syntax has several advantages over the old-style joins.  But yes, you can still use a `where` clause with modern join syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Simply like that :

```
SELECT 
    tasks.is AS taskId,
    item1.item1_name AS item1Name,
    item2.item2_name AS item2Name
FROM tasks
JOIN users ON users.task_id = tasks.id
JOIN notes ON notes.task_id = tasks.id
LEFT JOIN item1 ON item1.id = tasks.item1_id
LEFT JOIN item2 ON item2.id = tasks.item2_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    SELECT tasks.id AS taskID, item1.name AS item1Name, item2.name AS item2Name
    FROM tasks LEFT JOIN 
    ON tasks.item1_id = item1.id 
    LEFT JOIN item2 on tasks.item1_id = item2.id 
    JOIN users on users.task_id = tasks.id 
     JOIN notes on notes.task_id = tasks.id; 
    WHERE users.task_id = tasks.id
    AND notes.task_id = tasks.id;
```