# joining multiple tables in informix of Cisco CUCM

Tags: informix

I have 2 queries and their result as below-

1)

```
select a.pkid,a.name,c.buttonnum,c.label from device a, phonetemplate b, phonebutton c where a.name='SEPE8BA70FA173D' and a.fkphonetemplate=b.pkid and c.fkphonetemplate=b.pkid and (c.tkfeature=9 or c.tkfeature=2) and c.label like 'Speed Dial%'

pkid      name            buttonnum label
=====     ==============  ========= ============

6c9a81b4 SEPE8BA70FA173D  4         Speed Dial 2
6c9a81b4 SEPE8BA70FA173D  5         Speed Dial 3
6c9a81b4 SEPE8BA70FA173D  6         Speed Dial 4
6c9a81b4 SEPE8BA70FA173D  3         Speed Dial 1
6c9a81b4 SEPE8BA70FA173D  7         Speed Dial 5
```

2)
select

```
 a.pkid,a.name,d.speeddialindex,d.speeddialnumber,d.label,d.labelascii from device a,speeddial d where d.fkdevice=a.pkid and a.name='SEPE8BA70FA173D';

pkid       name            speeddialindex speeddialnumber label labelascii
========  ===============  ============== =============== ===== ==========

6c9a81b4  SEPE8BA70FA173D  2              *69777777732#   Umesh
6c9a81b4  SEPE8BA70FA173D  4              2000            A     A
6c9a81b4  SEPE8BA70FA173D  5              2002            B     B
```

I want to left join above 2 queries so that my result
a.

```
pkid                                 a.name        d.speeddialindex d.speeddialnumber d.label d.labelascii   c.label
========== =============== ============== ===============     ===== ==========       ==========

6c9a81b4   SEPE8BA70FA173D 2              *69777777732#      Umesh                   Speed Dial 2
6c9a81b4   SEPE8BA70FA173D 4              2000               A      A                Speed Dial 4
6c9a81b4   SEPE8BA70FA173D 5              2002               B      B                Speed Dial 5
6c9a81b4   SEPE8BA70FA173D 3                                                         Speed Dial 3
6c9a81b4   SEPE8BA70FA173D 1                                                         Speed Dial 1
```

I tried below but getting syntax error

```
select
    a.pkid pkid1,
    a.name,
    c.buttonnum,
    c.label,
    d.speeddialindex,
    d.speeddialnumber,
    d.label,
    d.labelascii,
    d.fkdevice fkdevice1
from device a,
     phonetemplate b,
     phonebutton c
where a.name='SEPE8BA70FA173D'
    and a.fkphonetemplate=b.pkid
    and c.fkphonetemplate=b.pkid
    and (c.tkfeature=9 or c.tkfeature=2)
    and c.label like 'Speed Dial%'
LEFT JOIN speeddial d ON pkid1 =fkdevice1
```

Regards,
Umesh

Comment: Your question is very difficult to read. Please use code tags to improve readability: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I tried to modify the post. Can u pls check now?

Comment: @Umesh, I know this is old, but are you just looking for a list of phone device names, and their associated speed dials?  You can construct a far simpler query for this on CUCM, and you don't need to `JOIN` on phone button templates.  If so, let me know, and I'll construct what you want as a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are [mixing ANSI-style joins with old-style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11179991/55209).
Second, `LEFT JOIN` is not in correct place, you must join before `WHERE` clause.

Below is ANSI-style query, check if it works

```
select
    a.pkid pkid1,
    a.name,
    c.buttonnum,
    c.label,
    d.speeddialindex,
    d.speeddialnumber,
    d.label,
    d.labelascii,
    d.fkdevice fkdevice1
from device a
join phonetemplate b on a.fkphonetemplate=b.pkid
join phonebutton c on c.fkphonetemplate=b.pkid
left join speeddial d ON a.pkid = d.fkdevice1
where a.name='SEPE8BA70FA173D'
    and (c.tkfeature=9 or c.tkfeature=2)
    and c.label like 'Speed Dial%'
```

Comment: Hi Artem, Thanks for reply but i am getting 15 records where as result should be only 5 record. 3 with number and label and 2 with null in number field.

Comment: i tried following query- 
select a.pkid,a.name,c.buttonnum,d.speeddialindex,d.speeddialnumber,d.label,d.labelascii from device a join phonetemplate b on a.fkphonetemplate=b.pkid join phonebutton c  on (a.fkphonetemplate=b.pkid and c.fkphonetemplate=b.pkid and (c.tkfeature=9 or c.tkfeature=2) and c.label like 'Speed Dial%')  left join speeddial d on a.pkid=d.fkdevice where a.name='SEPE8BA70FA173D'    


but this also returns 15 records.

Can u pls suggest what wrong I am doing?