# SQL query from multiple tables with missing fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Hoping someone can help me out. I have 5 tables, simplified examples below:

**catalog_items**: Stores information about items in a catalog.

```
CREATE TABLE catalog_items (
  item_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  create_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  valid TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

  PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);
```

**users**: Stores user information.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  valid TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

**user_contribution_types**: Users can contribute items to the catalog to earn credits, this table describes what type of contribution it is and how much they earn.

```
CREATE TABLE user_contribution_types (
  type_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  credits DECIMAL(5,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  valid TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

  PRIMARY KEY (type_id)
);
```

**user_contributions**: Table to relate all of the above (which user contributed x item).

```
CREATE TABLE user_contributions (
  user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  item_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  type_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  create_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  valid TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

  FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
    REFERENCES catalog_items(item_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
    REFERENCES user_contribution_types(type_id)
);
```

**pending_items**: All contributions must be approved, so they're stored in a temporary table. *These entries might be coming from new users without an account yet*, which is why there is only an email and not a `user_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE pending_items (
  pending_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  create_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  valid TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

  PRIMARY KEY (pending_id)
);
```

### Question

What I am attempting to do is select both approved and pending items from the catalog; however, the best I've come up with so far is to split them up:

Select only approved contributions:

```
SELECT a.item_id, c.title, a.create_date, b.description, b.credits
FROM user_contributions a, user_contribution_types b, catalog_items c
WHERE a.type_id = b.type_id AND a.item_id = c.item_id
AND a.valid = TRUE AND b.valid = TRUE AND c.valid = TRUE
ORDER BY c.create_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Select only pending contributions:

```
SELECT pending_id, title, create_date FROM pending_items WHERE email = 'example@email.com' AND valid = TRUE
ORDER BY create_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Is there a way to combine the above 2 queries to get a result set like the following, where missing fields simply display as `NULL`?

```
| item_or_pending_id | title | create_date         | description | credits | approved |
| ------------------ | ----- | ------------------- | ----------- | ------- | -------- |
| 14                 | test4 | 2017-04-08 04:41:21 | bar         | 1.00    | true     |
| 14                 | test3 | 2017-04-06 01:23:45 | NULL        | NULL    | false    |
| 11                 | test2 | 2017-02-03 12:30:00 | NULL        | NULL    | false    |
| 9                  | test1 | 2017-01-25 05:16:18 | foo         | 1.00    | true     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes :-)

```
SELECT a.item_id AS item_or_pending_id, 
       c.title, 
       a.create_date, 
       b.description, 
       b.credits, 
       true      AS approved 
FROM   user_contributions a, 
       user_contribution_types b, 
       catalog_items c 
WHERE  a.type_id = b.type_id 
       AND a.item_id = c.item_id 
       AND a.valid = true 
       AND b.valid = true 
       AND c.valid = true 
UNION 
SELECT pending_id, 
       title, 
       create_date, 
       NULL, 
       NULL, 
       false 
FROM   pending_items 
WHERE  email = 'example@email.com' 
       AND valid = true 
ORDER  BY create_date DESC 
LIMIT  0, 10
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Why would anyone upvote an answer that uses commas in the `FROM` clause?

Comment: Sorry, I altered the original query to the minimum. I am not supposed to refactor his work. So since it seems it requires clarification, people wondering may take a peak at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11180050/1291428

Comment: So, to refactor I should replace the `WHERE` clause with `JOIN...ON`s?

Comment: @mistermartin replace commas with joins yes. You still might want to keep some filters in the where clause, like email and valid